# Does knowing the population mean affect hypothesis testing for the mean?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

There's a lot of text there which you may ignore. I just posted it all for background if needed. I'm having issues with parts $(c)$ and $(d)$. I don't understand how knowing the population mean would influence hypothesis testing for the mean.

Just for a bit of background, hypothesis tests for the mean were done for $200$ different samples and the p values were recorded. And $29.5%$ of these values were less than $0.1$, in other words reject the null hypothesis below

[image]

Comment: You might naively hope that if the null hypothesis is in fact correct then  about $10\%$ of your tests would reject the null hypothesis at the $10\%$ level

Comment: Wow, really? Thank you